# Got error while inserting Dataset into a database Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the error

> String or binary data would be truncated.

The data for table-valued parameter "@tblCustomers" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is:

> Msg 8152, state: 10
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is the user-defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[recType] AS TABLE
(
   [refid] [int] NULL,
   [fromid] [varchar](13) NULL,
   [toid] [varchar](13) NULL,
   [message] [int] NULL,
   [status] [varchar](13) NULL,
)
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INSERT_RECVSMS]
    @tblCustomers recType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO RecieveSMS(Refid, fromID, Toid, message, status)
        SELECT 
            refid, fromid, toid, message, status 
        FROM @tblCustomers
END
```

Comment: Did you googled for that error message?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you so much for the  valuable information Mr.  FLICKER

Comment: Well, show us the **table structure!** Somewhere, you must have a mismatch of one of the `varchar` columns which you need to fix....

Answer (score 4):

Error message is very clear. Target/source table column is to small to hold string value.

Change the size for string columns to **appropriate values**:

```
[fromid] [varchar](13) NULL
-- 
[fromid] [varchar](xxx) NULL,
```

Comment: it still shows the error "Invalid object name 'RecieveSMS'."  I am using LINQPaD 4 ..  where i can find user defined table type.......i just created created the type ,. its succeeded ,,but i could not able find my user defined table type in LINQPaD...pease help me